# To Solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To Solve: $\displaystyle (1+x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0$

My Attempt: Take $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=p$

Now we have: $\displaystyle (1+x^2)\frac{dp}{dx}+1+p^2=0$

$\displaystyle \frac{dp}{1+p^2}=-\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)}$

Integrating, $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}p=-\tan^{-1}x$

So now, can we take this as $\displaystyle p = -x$ ?

If I can,we end with: $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=-x+c_1$

The answer seems different: $\displaystyle y=c_1x+(c_1^2+1)\log(x-c_1)+c_2$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you forgot to add in a constant, when you solve for $p$, this seems to complicate things

Comment: It will be $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}p=-\tan^{-1}x+c_1 $  This does not change anything

Comment: what about when you take $\tan$ of both sides? you will have $p=\tan(-\tan^{-1}(x)+c_1)$

Comment: Oh .. this becomes unwieldy .. How to solve this ..

Comment: $$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$$ hence (with $c = \tan c_1$) $$ \tan(-\tan^{-1} x + c_1) = \frac{-x + c}{1 + cx} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing my above comment. We have 
$$ y' = p = \tan\bigl(-\tan x + c\bigr) = \frac{c_1-x}{1+c_1x }. $$
Now in case $c_1 = 0$, we have $y' = -x$, hence $y = c_2 - \frac 12 x^2$. Otherwise we have 
$$ y' \frac{c_1 - x}{1 + c_1x} =  -\frac 1{c_1}\frac{-c_1^2 + c_1x}{1+c_1x}
  = -\frac 1{c_1} \cdot \left( 1 - (1+c_1^2)\frac 1{1+c_1 x} \right) 
$$
Hence 
$$ y = c_2 - \frac 1{c_1} \cdot \left( x - \frac{1+c_1^2}{c_1}\log(1 + c_1 x)\right) $$